# UI flickering while back pressed in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an android app with a number of activities. While switching between activities and then press back button a very short flickering occurs. I test adding this line in both `onBackPressed` and `onResume`:

```java
overridePendingTransition(0,0);
```

also I add this line to my theme style:

```xml
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
```

I did not find any solution. 
here is a short video:
[image]
Thanks for any help

Comment: It's unclear what exactly is happening - you may have better luck if you include a video of what the problem is.

Comment: @RyanMentley I Edit my post

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line to your theme style. It will delay a little bit the presentation by removing the flickering.

```
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```